# No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5

**How Can I Fix It**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from Pyqt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
```

result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
```

Comment: what result do you get when executing: `import PyQt5`

Comment: Have you installed PyQt5, i.e. 'python -m pip install PyQt5' or 'python3 -m pip install PyQt5'? Also I'm not familiar with this package but it likely depends on Qt5 as a minimum and python packages often don't install all their own dependencies