# ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets after converting python2 to python3 and pyqt4 to pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4, python-2.x

I have a program that was written in python2 and PyQt4 that I want to upgrade/convert to python3 and PyQt5.
I have changed the code/syntax from python2 to 3, and fixed the imports from PyQt4 to PyQt5, but I still get an error message saying that classes from PyQt5 failed to import.

Here is the import statement:
`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`

And the error message:

```
  File "./main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets
```

I have installed python3 and PyQt5, and chosen default interpreter in VSCode to be python3.8. Just need some guidance to the right direction forward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411129/no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwidgets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192101/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwidgets